# How to do a horizontal cover segue using storyboards?

Tags: ios, storyboard

There is a vertical cover transition.  I have been looking around the web for how to do a horizontal cover with no success.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no horizontal cover transition provided in iOS. You'll have to create your own UIStoryboardSegue subclass and implement your own transition animation.

One way to animate the kind of transition I think you're looking for is something like this (*warning: untested code*):

```
// add newView to window
[oldView.window insertSubview:newView aboveSubview:oldView];

// assuming newView and oldView both sized to fill screen,
//   position newView just to the right of oldView
newView.center = oldView.center + oldView.frame.size.width;

// slide newView over oldView, then remove oldView
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{ newView.center = oldView.center; }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ [oldView removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Comment: What do you need help with? Creating a segue, or animating the transition? The UIStoryboardSegue reference page covers subclassing, and you'll probably want to use Core Animation to do the actual transition.

Comment: http://blog.jh-lim.com/2011/11/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues/ This looks like it... I will play with this.  Thanks for letting me know what to look for.

Comment: I got the “custom transition” working...  I still don’t know how to do cover horizontal.. it doesn’t seem to be an option under [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:ctrl.view
                             cache:NO];

Comment: I think you're going to have to position the destination controller's view just off screen to the right or left of the current view and then animate it's position to move it onto the screen.

Comment: I’ve been looking for some example code for doing this... haven’t found any yet.  It should be a rather simple one... just linear.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks again.

Comment: Added a snippet above that should do about what you want. You might have to tweak it to get it to work -- I don't have time to play with it right now.

Comment: Link above is broken. Please use http://blog.jimjh.com/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues.html

Answer (score 1):

When you use a navigation controller and then push and pop views from it the effect is a horizontal cover.

Answer (score -1):

As answered by T.J. above, use a navigation controller and it will default to horizontal cover automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32240466)